# How to set a PHP variable inside an `str_replace`?

Tags: php

What is the correct form to make `$id` behave as a PHP variable inside the `str_replace` command? I've tried wrapping the `$id` inside with `{`, or `.`, but nothing helped. I'm not even sure how to define the problem I'm having here so I didn't really know how to Google this:

```
$id="Something";

$new = str_replace('?abc', '?id=$id&abc', $original);
```

Comment: have you tried '?id=' . $id . '&abc'

Comment: '?id=' . $id . '&abc' does not work?

Comment: RTM: [strings-Single quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). I suggest you to read it all...

Comment: @Yurich it does work, thanks, I just didn't apply it in the right form.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to concatenate strings in PHP. In your example, it would be either:

```
$new = str_replace('?abc', '?id=' . $id . '&abc', $original);
```

or

```
$new = str_replace('?abc', "?id=$id&abc", $original);
```

Note that the first option is slightly more efficient, and the spaces are optional.

Comment: This won't work. As FirstOne stated *RTM: [strings-double quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). I suggest you to read it all...*

Comment: `$new = str_replace('?abc', '?id=' . $id . '&abc', $original);` no quotes around the variable, else it will fail

Comment: Quotes around variables work if they are double quotes

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I believe the issue is that the answer has single quotes around the variable.

Comment: Mixing single and double quotes in your second example is no good.

Answer (score -1):

i think it needs to be work like this.

```
$search = 's';
$replace = 'r';
$subject = 'subject';

$result = str_replace($search,$replace,$subject);

var_dump($result);
```

and the result will be 'rubject'.

Comment: [*What?*](http://previews.123rf.com/images/stuartphoto/stuartphoto1205/stuartphoto120500715/13564622-Puzzled-Confused-Lost-Signpost-Shows-Puzzling-Problem-Stock-Photo.jpg)